# What is the cause of PropertyReferenceException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I shared the models, repositories and controllers I have created below. The error message is attached. What is the cause of the `PropertyReferenceException`? What do I need to change?

Player

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String playerName;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String playerSurname;

    @Column
    private int playerAge;



    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public String getPlayerSurname() {
        return playerSurname;
    }

    public void setPlayerSurname(String playerSurname) {
        this.playerSurname = playerSurname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPlayerAge() {
        return playerAge;
    }

    public void setPlayerAge(int playerAge) {
        this.playerAge = playerAge;
    }

    @OneToOne
    private Team team;

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }


}
```

Team

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String teamName;

    @Column
    private String teamCountry;

    public Team(){
    }

    public int getTeamId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setTeamId(int teamId) {
        this.id = teamId;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getTeamCountry() {
        return teamCountry;
    }

    public void setTeamCountry(String teamCountry) {
        this.teamCountry = teamCountry;
    }

}
```

PlayerRepository

```
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Integer>{
    List<Player> findPlayersByName(String playerName);
    List<Player> findPlayersBySurname(String playerSurname);
    List<Player> findPlayersByAge(int playerAge);

}
```

TeamRepository

```
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Integer>{
    List<Team> findTeamsByName(String teamName);
    List<Team> findTeamsByCountry(String teamCountry);

}
```

TeamController

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8000/")
@RestController
public class TeamController {
    @Autowired
    PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    @Autowired
    TeamRepository teamRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void main() {
        //create teams by manual    
        Team barcelona = new Team();
        Team juventus = new Team();
        Team arsenal = new Team();

        barcelona.setTeamName("Barcelona");
        barcelona.setTeamCountry("Spain");

        juventus.setTeamName("Juventus");
        juventus.setTeamCountry("Italy");

        arsenal.setTeamName("Arsenal");
        arsenal.setTeamCountry("England");

        this.teamRepository.save(barcelona);
        this.teamRepository.save(juventus);
        this.teamRepository.save(arsenal);


        //create players by manual
        Player messi = new Player();
        Player ronaldo = new Player();
        Player ozil = new Player();

        messi.setPlayerName("Lionel");
        messi.setPlayerSurname("Messi");
        messi.setPlayerAge(31);
        messi.setTeam(barcelona);

        ronaldo.setPlayerName("Cristiano");
        ronaldo.setPlayerSurname("Ronaldo");
        ronaldo.setPlayerAge(32);
        ronaldo.setTeam(juventus);

        ozil.setPlayerName("Mesut");
        ozil.setPlayerSurname("Ozil");
        ozil.setPlayerAge(29);
        ozil.setTeam(arsenal);

        this.playerRepository.save(messi);
        this.playerRepository.save(ronaldo);
        this.playerRepository.save(ozil);
    }   

    //**PLAYER**
    @GetMapping(value="/getAllPLayers")
    public List<Player> getAllPlayers(){
        return playerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value="getPlayerByName")
    public List<Player> getPlayerByName(@RequestParam("playerName") String playerName){
        return playerRepository.findPlayersByName(playerName);
    }

    @PostMapping(value="getPlayerBySurname")
    public List<Player> getPlayerBySurname(@RequestParam("playerSurname") String playerSurname){
        return playerRepository.findPlayersBySurname(playerSurname);
    }   

    @PostMapping(value="getPlayerByAge")
    public List<Player> getPlayerByAge(@RequestParam("playerAge") int playerAge){
        return playerRepository.findPlayersByAge(playerAge);
    }   


    //**TEAM**
    @GetMapping(value="/getAllTeams")
    public List<Team> getAllTeams(){
        return teamRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/getTeamsByName")
    public List<Team> getTeamByName(@RequestParam("teamName") String teamName){
        return teamRepository.findTeamsByName(teamName);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/getTeamsByCountry")
    public List<Team> getTeamByCountry(@RequestParam("teamCountry") String teamCountry){
        return teamRepository.findTeamsByCountry(teamCountry);
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-29 14:01:22.391 ERROR 18540 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'teamController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'playerRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.repository.PlayerRepository.findPlayersBySurname(java.lang.String)! No property surname found for type Player!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.FmanagementApplication.main(FmanagementApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'playerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.repository.PlayerRepository.findPlayersBySurname(java.lang.String)! No property surname found for type Player!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.repository.PlayerRepository.findPlayersBySurname(java.lang.String)! No property surname found for type Player!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:84) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:561) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property surname found for type Player!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is in the stack trace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.demo.repository.PlayerRepository.findPlayersBySurname(java.lang.String)! No property surname found for type Player!

Your Spring Data JPA repository method name must match your entity properties. Right now it should be:

```
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Integer>{
    List<Player> findByPlayerName(String playerName);
    List<Player> findByPlayerSurname(String playerSurname);
    List<Player> findByPlayerAge(int playerAge);
}
```

Although you probably should consider renaming `Player` entity fields from `playerName`, `playerSurname` and `playerAge` to `name`, `surname` and `age`. This would allow you to define the repository as:

```
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Integer>{
    List<Player> findByName(String playerName);
    List<Player> findBySurname(String playerSurname);
    List<Player> findByAge(int playerAge);
}
```

Comment: spring terminal error message did not print. Tomcat start on 8080 port. Now I'm going to see if it adds to the mysql database.

Comment: Hi @Karol. Let the JPA repository method names by anything irrespective of the entity attribute names, the @Query(" some query here") should work too, right?

Comment: @robot_alien yes, but the point of Spring Data is convention over configuration, you should follow the naming convention instead of doing a `@Query` workaround

Answer (score 0):

**Since there is "@OneToOne" Relationship Entity between Team and Player".**

**Just change Both the Repositories to this: It'll work**

**But it would be better if you had gone for "@OneToMany" Entity Relationship.**

**Update 1:**

Player:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    @Column
    private int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String playerName;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String playerSurname;

    @Column
    private int playerAge;



    public String getPlayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public String getPlayerSurname() {
        return playerSurname;
    }

    public void setPlayerSurname(String playerSurname) {
        this.playerSurname = playerSurname;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getPlayerAge() {
        return playerAge;
    }

    public void setPlayerAge(int playerAge) {
        this.playerAge = playerAge;
    }

    @OneToOne
    private Team team; // Naming Conventions for Custom Methods declared in Interface. This object Name should be used for Custom Methods in Interface extending JpaRepository.

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }


}
```

PlayerRepository:

**According to the Naming Conventions for Custom Methods in Interface extending JpaRepository.**

**Method name should be in Camel Case Conventions starting with "findBy" follwed by Object name i.e. "findByTeam".**

**And then the name of the variable i.e. "findByTeamPlayerName"**

```
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Integer>{
    List<Player> findByTeamPlayerName(String playerName);
    List<Player> findByTeamPlayerySurname(String playerSurname);
    List<Player> findByTeamPlayerAge(int playerAge);

}
```

TeamRepository

```
public interface TeamRepository extends JpaRepository<Team, Integer>{
    List<Team> findByTeamName(String teamName);
    List<Team> findByTeamCountry(String teamCountry);

}
```